# ASP.NET Amazon ItemSearch

Tags: c#, asp.net

I would like to be able to look up items on either keyword such as "star trek" or straight up UPC. What I would like to get back is title, description, year, and a link to an image, type (dvd, books, music).

Does anyone know of any good examples, or care to explain how to do an amazon lookup similar to this, http://blogs.msdn.com/b/coding4fun/archive/2006/10/31/912260.aspx,
I would just use this, but it seems to be out of date and the source is no longer available.

Comment: link gives 403 forbidden. wayback machine leads here (?): https://web.archive.org/web/20211024072800/http://channel9.msdn.com/coding4fun/articles/Using-the-Amazon-Web-Service

Comment: @daniel-widdis this seems like a pretty clear-cut resource request, all answers are links to tools or outright spam.

Answer (score 4):

I wrote a little [C# Wrapper for Amazon ItemLookup](http://nathan.craddock.org/AmazonItemLookup) that hands you back a handy object graph. It only supports ItemLookup right now. I have the source up [on BitBucket](https://bitbucket.org/nkcraddock/amazonitemlookup).

You can make calls like:

```
var item = client.LookupByAsin("B0037X9N5U");
double? price = item.GetLowestPrice();
```

Answer (score 1):

Hi it is very easy with the following nuget
[Nager.AmazonProductAdvertising](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Nager.AmazonProductAdvertising) package

**nuget**

```
PM> Install-Package Nager.AmazonProductAdvertising
```

**Example**

```cs
var authentication = new AmazonAuthentication("accesskey", "secretkey");
var client = new AmazonProductAdvertisingClient(authentication, AmazonEndpoint.US);
var result = await client.GetItemsAsync("B0037X9N5U");
```